# Pandas conditional formatting columns and for loops

Tags: pandas, loops

I have the following dataframe.

```
{'patient': {0: 'Mark', 1: 'Susan', 2: 'Andy', 3: 'Paula'},
 'blood pressure': {0: 45, 1: 36, 2: 35, 3: 92},
 'heart rate': {0: 60, 1: 65, 2: 98, 3: 59},
 'pulse': {0: 70, 1: 70, 2: 45, 3: 76},
 'weight': {0: 150, 1: 180, 2: 200, 3: 210},
 'height': {0: 178, 1: 170, 2: 165, 3: 168},
 'oxygen': {0: 92, 1: 99, 2: 96, 3: 97}}
```

Each numeric column has its own reference value stored as its own variable (but this could really be stored in any way necessary:

```
blood_pressure_ref = 36
heart_rate_ref = 70
pulse_ref = 60
weight_ref = 180
height_ref = np.nan
oxygen_ref = 96
cholesterol = 0.6
```

I can compare the values in each column to their respective reference values, to highlight higher/lower values using red/green for example with the following code:

```
df_styled = df.style\
    .applymap(lambda x: 'background-color: %s' % 'red' if x < blood_pressure_ref else 'background-color: %s' % 'green', subset = ['blood pressure'])\
    .applymap(lambda x: 'background-color: %s' % 'red' if x < heart_rate_ref else 'background-color: %s' % 'green', subset = ['heart rate'])\
    .applymap(lambda x: 'background-color: %s' % 'red' if x < pulse_ref else 'background-color: %s' % 'green', subset = ['pulse'])\
    .applymap(lambda x: 'background-color: %s' % 'red' if x < weight_ref else 'background-color: %s' % 'green', subset = ['weight'])\
    .applymap(lambda x: 'background-color: %s' % 'red' if x < height_ref else 'background-color: %s' % 'green', subset = ['height'])\
    .applymap(lambda x: 'background-color: %s' % 'red' if x < oxygen_ref else 'background-color: %s' % 'green', subset = ['oxygen'])
```

And this produces the desired effect, which I can export to Excel, using to_excel and with the engine 'openpyxl':

[image: Desired formatting]

But there are two issues here - firstly the code is repetitive, and secondly if a column isn't in the dataframe (e.g. weight or heart rate), we'll run into an error. Plus if an extra column is present, such as cholesterol, that column will be missed.

I've thought about doing list comprehension to get a list of the column headers, then remove the 'patient' column, so we're left with the columns to do the formatting on. But, I'm unsure of how to make this code more flexible. Also thought of using a for loop, but not sure how this would work with the code in its current format.

Any assistance please?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the reference values in a `dict` with keys matching the column names:

```py
references = {
    "blood pressure": 36,
    "heart rate": 70,
    "pulse": 60,
    "weight": 180,
    "height": np.nan,
    "oxygen": 96,
    "cholesterol": 0.6,
}
```

Then get the valid columns, checking if they exist in `df`, and their respective reference values:

```py
ref_columns = [col for col in references if col in df.columns]
ref_values = [references[col] for col in ref_columns]
```

And finally chain two calls to [`highlight_between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.highlight_between.html) passing all the columns and reference values at once.

The first call paints green the values greater or equal to reference, and the second call paints red the values smaller than reference.

```py
df.style.highlight_between(
    axis="columns", subset=ref_columns, color="green", left=ref_values, right=None, inclusive="left"
).highlight_between(
    axis="columns", subset=ref_columns, color="red", left=None, right=ref_values, inclusive="neither"
)
```

[image: highlighted dataframe]

The `height` column doesn't get colored as it has `np.nan` as a reference value, but you can do something like coloring the entire `df` green and then calling `highlight_between` to color cells below the reference value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single [`Styler.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) this way :

```
d = {
    "blood pressure": 36,
    "heart rate": 70,
    "pulse": 60,
    "weight": 180,
    "height": np.nan,
    "oxygen": 96,
    # add here more columns/values
}

def func(ser):
    return np.where(
        ser.lt(d.get(ser.name)),
        "background-color: red", "background-color: green"
    )

df_styled = df.style.apply(func, subset=list(d.keys()))

# df_styled.to_excel("output.xlsx", index=False) #uncomment to make a spreadsheet
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: how does that code work? I don't see any less than or equal to symbols?

Comment: [`lt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) (*lower than*) is equivalent to `<`.